# Packaging SQL Server Express 2012 install won't install due to user rights

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, installation

[image: User Account Control Window]

**Is there a way force the above permission window to elevate the user permissions?**

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you do not have enough rights granted for your installation.  See:

[SQL Server installation fails if the Setup account does not have certain user rights](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2000257)

Partial comments under **Cause**:

> This behavior is by design. In addition to adding the user account
>   that is running the Setup as a local administrator, the Setup user
>   account requires the following default user rights for the Setup to be
>   completed successfully

```
 -  Local Policy Object Display Name    User Right     
 -  Backup files and directories        SeBackupPrivilege  
 -  Debug Programs                      SeDebugPrivilege  
 -  Manage auditing and security log    SeSecurityPrivilege
```

Also review the comments at:

[InstallShield Limited Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020(v=vs.120).aspx)
 The Install Shield link also suggests [ClickOnce Security and Deployment.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.120).aspx)
 [Install SQL Server 2012 from the Installation Wizard (Setup)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132644/packaging-sql-server-express-2012-install-wont-install-due-to-user-rights)

If you do not have enough privileges then you *probably* need to either (1) pursue the extra privileges or (2) have someone with those privileges handle the install.

Comment: I will not have access to be able to change customers' PC user rights so that is not an option in our case. In testing I have found that on my VM with only one user (admin with full rights) the install fails with InstallShield LE installer but not if run from command line. So I can't guarantee that stating that an administrator must complete the install will work for all cases.

Comment: I understand that you are facing challenges, but the problem does not go away.  Updated to include reference to ClickOnce as another option.  (Not shilling for that, just pointing out the link.)

Comment: I guess my confusion is why it works when run in command line but not when running the same command from an installer.